# Azure openai connection with javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, api, azure-openai

I have created my chatbot with javascript and used open ai. I need to change it to azure open ai but can not find the connection details for javascript. This is how i connect with python :

```
import os
import openai
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_base = "https://test-azure-openai-d.openai.azure.com/"
openai.api_version = "2022-12-01"
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
```

This was the code in js for openai :

```
import express from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';

dotenv.config()

//console.log(process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY)
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
```

So i would need the connection in javascrip

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the [OpenAI package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai) does not support Azure endpoints yet.
You can refer to [this open issue](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/issues/53) on the GitHub repo.

So for now you have two options:
Make raw API calls using `fetch` or `axios`.
You can refer to [API reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/reference) on Azure website.

```js
const basePath = "https://test-azure-openai-d.openai.azure.com/"
const apiVersion = "2022-12-01"
const apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY

const url = `${basePath}/openai/deployments/${data.model}/completions?api-version=${apiVersion}`;

  const response = await fetch(url, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'api-key': `${apiKey}`,
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(data),
  });

  return await response.json();
```

Or use the [`azure-openai` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-openai)

```js
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "azure-openai"; 

this.openAiApi = new OpenAIApi(
   new Configuration({
      apiKey: this.apiKey,
      // add azure info into configuration
      azure: {
         apiKey: {your-azure-openai-resource-key},
         endpoint: {your-azure-openai-resource-endpoint},
         // deploymentName is optional, if you donot set it, you need to set it in the request parameter
         deploymentName: {your-azure-openai-resource-deployment-name},
      }
   }),
);
```

Comment: Hello @picsoung, thank you so much for your answer, i have put the 1st code into my script and i just get one error:

file:///C:/Users/gyorg/Desktop/OpenAI/server/server.js:20
const url = `${basePath}/openai/deployments/${data.model}/completions?api-version=${apiVersion}`;
                                              ^

ReferenceError: data is not defined 

Datamodel is not defined - what should i write here
And i commented out the response part

Comment: According to the [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/reference)
it refers to `The deployment name you chose when you deployed the model.`

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the [Azure OpenAi library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/openai-readme?view=azure-node-preview)